# Long Running Timer increasing Private Bytes in C#

Tags: c#, timer, garbage-collection

I created an application which runs in background and make use of 4 Timers for different purposes. On elapsed event of timers task is accomplished but Memory Private Bytes are growing.

I read about Timer classes and it is said that Timers must be disposed after once task is completed but the issue is timer must run in background to accomplish task.

```
class myservice
{

    public void Start()
    {
        Timer tActiveWin = new Timer();
        tActiveWin.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds;
        tActiveWin.Elapsed += TActiveWin_Elapsed;
        tActiveWin.AutoReset = true;
        tActiveWin.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void TActiveWin_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var win = new WindowEvents().GetActiveWindow();
        Console.WriteLine(win.activewindowtitle);
    }

    class WindowEvents
    {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

    public JsonAppEvents.Activewindow GetActiveWindow()
    {
        JsonAppEvents.Activewindow activeWin = new JsonAppEvents.Activewindow();

        IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();

        int processID = 0;
        int threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processID);


        using (Process p = Process.GetProcessById(processID))
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(256);
            if (GetWindowText(hWnd, text, 256) > 0)
            {
            text.ToString();
            }

            activeWin.activewindowfullpath = p.MainModule.FileName;
            activeWin.activewindowtitle = p.MainWindowTitle;
            activeWin.time = p.StartTime.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            activeWin.activewindowdescription = p.MainModule.ModuleName;

            p.Dispose();

            hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
            processID = 0;
            threadID = 0;
            text.Clear();
            text = null;
        }

        return activeWindow.Result;    
    }


class JsonAppEvents
{
    public class Activewindow
    {
        public string activewindowfullpath { get; set; }
        public string activewindowdescription { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }
        public string activewindowtitle { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I also did searches on Garbage Collection working and since in C# we can not control when memory will be claimed, I am stuck with more findings on it. Any clue on it will help.

Comment: Looks like your active window is never getting disposed since it is being returned to calling function : JsonAppEvents.Activewindow activeWin = new JsonAppEvents.Activewindow();

Comment: At what rate are private bytes increasing and how long did you try it? The GC is non-deterministic. Make a test by placing GC.Collect() at the end of the timer function.

Comment: I monitored it for around 4 hours and GC.Collect() wasn't much of help. It is increasing every 2 second with around 20 bytes.

Comment: @jdweng, ActiveWindow is set to Null. What else i can do to dispose it?

Comment: Make another test: Replace the timer with an infinite loop calling GetActiveWindow. Memory usage should now rise quickly and unambiguously.

Comment: Can't reproduce with the infinite loop.

Comment: Did you dispose the ActiveWindow?  There may be an object in JsonAppEvents that may not get disposed.

Comment: Yes, I did another test with infinite loop. Yes you are right it is increasing.

Comment: what should be the proper way to dispose it? JsonAppEvents only has string members in it.

Comment: Post executable code that demonstrates the issue. I cannot reproduce it in a console app. Maybe other code not shown here causes this. In the meantime I'm closing as cannot repro.

Comment: where i can post? because this comment box has limitations here.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `StringBuilder` and `GetWindowText`? Further, why `text.ToString()` alone?

Comment: You don't need to call `Dispose()` explicitly for an object controlled by a `using()` block - e.g. `p.Dispose()`. Even in case of an error within the `using()` block.

Comment: GetWindowText is capturing WindowTitle using Native Window Handle. Yes, I can remove text.Tostring();

Comment: Edit the question to post code.

Comment: My point is, there is nothing happening with the retrieved text afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the `SafeFileHandle`, unsafe handles aren't disposed automatically. So 
use the `CloseHandle()` Win32 API to discard unsafe handles. Size of a handle depends on the target architecture - it is either 32 or 64 bits. So declare the function and use it as follows:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]        
protected static extern bool CloseHandle([In] IntPtr Handle);
.
.
.
IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
.
.
.
CloseHandle(hWnd);
```

Comment: Window handles are not kernel handles and they can't be closed. An HWND *is* the window. It's like the process id as opposed to a process handle.

Comment: It did not solve the issue, and I am receiving SEH Exception in my debugging environment.

Comment: I have got reference of SafeWindowHandle from

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.110).aspx